# Stack Exchange blogs do not load properly over https

Tags: bug, ssl, blog-overflow, cloudflare

Currently none of the Stack Exchange blogs work over HTTPS. There are several different ways in which they seem to be broken, and the blogs don't seem to be getting served in a consistent manner.

**Stack Exchange Blog:**

- Served from a Stack Exchange IP
- Certificate is valid for `*.stackexchange.com`, `*.stackoverflow.com`, and others.
- No css or JS resources load. CSS resources are being loaded from `http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/themes/` and seem to be hard-coded to the `http` protocol and the `blog.stackoverflow.com` domain. The source is the same whether viewed from `blog.stackexchange.com` or `blog.stackoverflow.com`.

**Super User Blog:**

- Served from cloudflare IPs.
- Certificate is issued to `ssl4121.cloudflare.com`.
- Certificate is valid for `*.superuser.com` and some others.
- No CSS or JS are being loaded for the same reason as above. The resources are hard coded to be loaded from `http://blog.superuser.com/wp-content`.

**Server Fault Blog**, **Bicycles Blog**, **Gaming Blog**, **Mod Newsletter**:

- All are being served from cloudflare IPs.
- Certificate is issued to `ssl4121.cloudflare.com`.
- Certificate is *not* valid for any of these sites, so the sites do not load at all. The browser displays a certificate error.
- The certificate being presented is the same as for the SU blog, and is valid for:

  ```
  ssl4121.cloudflare.com
  *.superuser.com
  superuser.com
  teststackoverflow.com
  *.teststackoverflow.com
  *.wimdu.co.uk
  *.sstatic.net
  sstatic.net
  wimdu.co.uk
  ```